# Generate ssh keys in systemd-nspawn

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian, systemd-nspawn

I wrote a couple of scripts to download, customize and prepare a Raspbian image for Raspberry Pi.
Because the root file-system will be mounted in read-only I have to create the ssh keys BEFORE running the target the first time.

I found the ssh keys generation is handled by the service `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service` (by the way the exactly same file is also placed under `/lib/systemd/system/regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service`).

Here its content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Regenerate SSH host keys
Before=ssh.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=-/bin/dd if=/dev/hwrng of=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=4096
ExecStartPre=-/bin/sh -c "/bin/rm -f -v /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key*"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A -v
ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl disable regenerate_ssh_host_keys

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Hence I'm going to execute those commands inside the nspawn container in order to generate the keys during the configuration.

The problem is it looks for `/dev/hwrng` and `/dev/urandom` but I don't have them at this stage.
Furthermore I cannot disable the service using systemctl because inside the container I don't have dbus running. Is there another way to disable it? I don't want to remove the file itself if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `mask` the service manually by removing the `/etc/systemd/...` file and then creating a symlink of

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service
```

to `/dev/null` instead of a symlink to

```
/lib/systemd/system/regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service
```

Like this :

```
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service /dev/null
```

When you unmask a service it creates the symlink back to the file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/filename`. Following is how you would unmask it :

```
systemctl umask regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service
```

Or recreate the symlink.

```
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service /lib/systemd/system/regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service
```

PS: Remember to delete the symlink to `/dev/null`